# Qt-OpenCV:How to display grayscale images(opencv) in Qt

Tags: image, qt, opencv, grayscale

I have a piece of code here.
This is a camera capture application using OpenCV and Qt(for GUI).

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{

    cv::VideoCapture cap(0);

    if(!cap.isOpened()) return;

    //namedWindow("edges",1);
    QVector<QRgb> colorTable;
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) colorTable.push_back(qRgb(i, i, i));

    QImage img;
    img.setColorTable(colorTable);

    for(;;)
    {
        cap >> image;
        cvtColor(image, edges, CV_BGR2GRAY);
        GaussianBlur(edges, edges, cv::Size(7,7), 1.5, 1.5);
        Canny(edges, edges, 0, 30, 3);
        //imshow("edges", edges);
        if(cv::waitKey(30) >= 0) break;

    // change color channel ordering
    //cv::cvtColor(image,image,CV_BGR2RGB);

    img =  QImage((const unsigned char*)(edges.data),
    image.cols,image.rows,QImage::Format_Indexed8);

    // display on label
    ui->label->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(img,Qt::AutoColor));
    // resize the label to fit the image
    ui->label->resize(ui->label->pixmap()->size());   

    }
}
```

Initially "edges" is  displayed in red with green background.Then it switches to blue background. This switching is happening randomly.
How can I display white edges in a black background in a stable manner.

Comment: Make sure your operations are not limited to one or two channels, if you create a resulting image of 3 channels and manipulate one, make sure you do that to rest of the two. Or create a single channel image in the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, add the `img.setColorTable(colorTable);` just before the `// display on label`comment.

For more details, you create your image and affect the color table at the begining of your code:

```
QImage img;
img.setColorTable(colorTable);
```

Then in the infinite loop, you are doing the following:

```
img =  QImage((const unsigned char*)(edges.data), image.cols, image.rows, QImage::Format_Indexed8);
```

What happens is that you destroy the image created at the begining of your code, the color map for this new image is not set and thus uses the default resulting in a colored output.